# How to handle distributed transaction using jpa

Tags: mysql, mongodb, hibernate, jpa, jta

I have a requirement where I need to insert the reduced in two different databases MYSQL and mongodb. In the case of fail over scenario entire transaction should be rolled back.
Please help as early as possible. Need to implement this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to define two database connections and thus also two different persistence units defined in your

> persistence.xml

file.

After that, just create 2 separate EntityManagers in each DAO method.

Try the following:

```
persistFoo(Foo f) {
    // Create these EntityManagers with a proper connection/persistence unit name
    EntityManager emMySQL = //your MySQL db
    EntityManager emMongo = //your Mongo db

    EntityTransaction txMySQL = emMySQL.getTransaction();
    EntityTransaction txMongo = emMongo.getTransaction();    

    try {
       txMySQL.begin();
       emMySQL.persist(f);
       txMySQL.commit();

       txMongo.begin();
       emMongo.persist(f);
       txMongo.commit();
    } catch(Exception e) {
       if(txMySQL.isActive()) {
          txMySQL.rollback();
       }
       if(txMongo.isActive()) {
          txMongo.rollback();
       }
    } finally {
       emMySQL.close();
       emMongo.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I need to rollback both the database transaction if anyone fails.This should be in sync.

Comment: Alright, so in one method this is not possible, because transactions can't be rollbacked after a commit. I will try to figure out a workaround and tell you. In the meantime you can try out nested transactions and see if that works in JPA.